# Manifest file called package.json giving a syntax error for kiosk 3dwayfinder

Tags: syntax, 3d, manifest, kiosk

```
{
"window": {
"kiosk": true,
"toolbar": false,
"frame": true
 },
"main": "http://static.3dwayfinder.com/projects/code/station/#{"kiosk":2}",
"name": "3D Wayfinder"
}
```

error I am getting is at the " before kiosk
syntax error
what do I need to change to get this working?